# statement is true for L^2 not for L^1

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

A problem about L^p space in Bass's real analysis book.

Define $g_n(x) = n\chi_{[0,n^{-3}]}(x)$:

(1) Show that if $f \in L^2([0, 1])$, then $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)g_n(x)dx\rightarrow 0$

(2)Show that there exist $f \in L^1([0, 1])$ such that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)g_n(x)dx \nrightarrow 0$;

I've no idea how to prove that, please give any hint or idea. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, you can use Cauchy-Schwarz.

For the second one, how about $f(x) = x^{-\frac{2}{3}}$

Comment: thanks, here is what I am thinking (1) $f, g_n \in L^2$ and $\int {g_n}^{2} dx \rightarrow 0$, then by Cauchy Schwarz ineq, we get it;
(2) it approaches to 1.

Comment: Actually, for the 2), it's equal to 3 : $$\int n x^{-\frac{2}{3}} dx = 3nx^{\frac{1}{3}}$$ so between $0$ and $n^{-3}$ you get $3$ and not $1$